# Teste unitário em Ruby não funciona

Tags: ruby, testes-de-unidade, minitest

Estou executando um simples teste unitário e na minha máquina não mostra se o teste executou com sucesso ou erro.
Meu código abaixo deveria dar uma falha.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class MagicBallTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_ask_returns_an_answer
    magic_ball = MagicBall.new
    assert magic_ball.ask("hatever") != nil
  end
end

class MagicBall
  def ask question
    "Whatever"
  end
end
```

E o console mostra o seguinte:

```
Testing started at 12:41 ...
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/rafael/RubymineProjects/Miojo/app/tests/magic_ball_test.rb --name=test_ask_returns_an_answer
Run options: --name=test_ask_returns_an_answer --seed 45592

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001261s, 793.3001 runs/s, 793.3001 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Fica uma mensagem na parte do lado escrito: "Test framework quit unexpectedly".

Alguém já passou por isso e o que pode ser o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Esse não é um erro do Minitest, e sim do RubyMine.

Você precisa fazer o setup do Minitest para a IDE que está utilizando. Aqui vai o [tutorial oficial da JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/minitest-reporters.html) de como fazer o setup dele.